# Excel Matching Customer Orders by Item and Quantity

Tags: excel, excel-2010

**Brief**:
I have a large dataset, inside of which are Individual customer orders by item and quantity. What I'm trying to do is get excel to tell me which order numbers contain exact matches (in terms of items and quantities) to each other. Ideally, I'd like to have a tolerance of say 80% accuracy which I can flex to purpose but I'll take anything to get me off the ground.

**Existing Solution**:
At the moment, I've used concatenation to pair item with quantity, pivoted and then put the order references as column and concat as rows with quantity as data (sorted by quantity desc) and I'm visually scrolling across/down to find matches and then manually stripping in my main data where necessary. I have about 2,500 columns to check so was hoping I could find a more suitable solution with excel doing the legwork on identification.

Index/matching works at cross referencing a match for the concatenation but of course, the order numbers (which are unique) are different so its not giving me matches ACROSS orders.

Fingers crossed!

**EDIT:** 
[Data set with outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lIsO.jpg)

As you can see, the bottom order reference has no correlation to the orders above it so is not listed as a match to the orders above but 3 are identical and 1 has a slightly different item but MOSTLY matches.

Comment: Can you please post an example image of your data set as well as your expected output? It'll help us better visualize what you're looking for.

Comment: If you have the concat column as an identifier can't you do data -> remove duplicates across your table based on that column?

Comment: I can't use the concat to remove duplicates as the order ref will be different. What i'm trying to do is match different order numbers where they contain the same items and quanties. I'll create an example data set and try to post. Thanks for the support